# AWS lambda, Unknown service: 'quicksight'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3

I am using boto3 API to create groups in quicksight from lambda, having role full access to quicksight

```
import boto3

quicksight_client = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name='us-east-1', 
                                 aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID, 
                                 aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # list groups present in quicksight
    response = quicksight_client.list_groups(
        AwsAccountId=event['AWS Account ID'],
        Namespace='default'
    )
```

facing following error

`Unknown service: 'quicksight'. Valid service names are: acm, acm-pca, alexaforbusiness, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, appsync, athena, autoscaling, autoscaling-plans, batch, budgets, ce, cloud9, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, comprehend, config, connect, cur, datapipeline, dax, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dlm, dms, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, eks, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, fms, gamelift, glacier, glue, greengrass, guardduty, health, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, iot-jobs-data, iot1click-devices, iot1click-projects, iotanalytics, kinesis, kinesis-video-archived-media, kinesis-video-media, kinesisanalytics, kinesisvideo, kms, lambda, lex-models, lex-runtime, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, macie, marketplace-entitlement, marketplacecommerceanalytics, mediaconvert, medialive, mediapackage, mediastore, mediastore-data, mediatailor, meteringmarketplace, mgh, mobile, mq, mturk, neptune, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, pi, pinpoint, polly, pricing, rds, redshift, rekognition, resource-groups, resourcegroupstaggingapi, route53, route53domains, s3, sagemaker, sagemaker-runtime, sdb, secretsmanager, serverlessrepo, servicecatalog, servicediscovery, ses, shield, sms, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, transcribe, translate, waf, waf-regional, workdocs, workmail, workspaces, xray`

when same code is executed from my computer its working, but not from lambda

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What version of boto3 and botocore do you have installed? Most likely you need to update your libraries.

Comment: I am working on AWS lambda, it has pre-installed boto3

Comment: you get that when executing on AWS lambda? Are you working with the lambda code editor?

Comment: yes i get this error when executing with aws lambda code inline , i.e code editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested with boto3-1.9.71 & botocore-1.12.71 and it is working fine.

Steps to package latest version of boto3.

1. Create a directory for your lambda function on your local machine
2. Use below command to install latest boto3 into your new directory

   pip install boto3 --target /path/to/your/directory
3. Navigate to new your directory and create a new file called lambda_function.py (or any name. make sure you have filename.function name as your handler)
4. Paste below code into .py file

   import boto3
   print(boto3.**version**)
   client = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name='us-east-1')
   response = client.list_groups(
       AwsAccountId='0123456789',
       Namespace='default'
   )
5. You can execute this py file on your local machine with proper access keys / profile to test of the client is getting created
6. Now from within the new directory select all the directories and files and create a zip file.
7. Upload this zip file to lambda and you should be able to execute the function without errors.

Comment: That works like a champ!!! I followed steps its executing
previously i followed  "With a Virtual Environment" steps, aws document from windows machine it didn't work !!

Comment: what would be the reason for not working when followed same steps to install from virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

Which AWS services are supported by `boto3` isn't directly defined in [`boto3`](https://github.com/boto/boto3/), but in [`botocore`](https://github.com/boto/botocore). For Quicksight support, you need at least version `1.12.49` of `botocore`, which is the version where Quicksight support got added (although the changelog erroneously talks about [updated Quicksight support](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#11249)).

When using AWS Lambda you can either use an AWS-provided version of `boto3` or bundle your own. As you're using the AWS-provided versions, your code currently runs with outdated versions of [`botocore` (1.10.74) and `boto3` (1.7.74)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), as AWS hasn't updated them in a while. These old versions don't support Quicksight yet.

We can only speculate why AWS stopped updating `botocore` and `boto3` for the AWS Lambda environment, but it might have to do with some backwards-incompatible changes introduced with [`botocore` 1.12.0](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html#upgrading-to-1-12-0) and [`boto3` 1.9.0](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/upgrading.html#id1).

To solve your problem you can add recent versions of `botocore` and `boto3`, which do support Quicksight, to your [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html), to use them, instead of the AWS-provided ones.

Comment: i tried with deploying package with new version of boto3, still same error @Dunedan

Comment: The most likely problem is that you didn't package it correctly, so your Lambda function still did use the AWS-provided versions. To check if that's the case, you can check which boto3-version your running code is using: 
`import boto3`
`print(boto3.__version__)`